# Objective-C, unsigned long _Nullable

Tags: objective-c, integer, clang

I get a warning when I compile my code, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

> warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
>   'unsigned long *' with an expression of type 'unsigned long
>   _Nullable'

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"foo": @420};
unsigned long *num = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] unsignedLongValue];
NSString *oct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%o", num];
NSLog(@"%04u", [oct intValue]); // 0644
```

The output is correct (I'm converting a number to octal format), but I guess my code isn't up to par with the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes here -

1) unsigned long is not an object but primitive.
You simply need to remove the "*" before num as follow -

```
unsigned long num = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] unsignedLongValue];
```

2) The format of unsigned long is %lu and not %o as you mentioned.

```
NSString *oct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", num];
```

So, the correct code should be -

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"foo": @420};
unsigned long num = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] unsignedLongValue];
NSString *oct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", num];
NSLog(@"%04u", [oct intValue]); // 0644
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work (the warnings went away):

```
unsigned long num = (unsigned long)[[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] unsignedLongValue];
NSString *oct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lo", num];
```

Comment: `(unsigned long)` is not required.